# Active record, como substituir o uniq pelo distinct de forma correta?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, active-record

Estou tentando recuperar os meses onde tenho respostas a uma pesquisa desta maneira:

```
Answers.pluck('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at)').uniq


(0.7ms)  SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) FROM `answers`
=> [3]
```

Desta maneira tenho o resultado esperado, mas recebo um warning do rails:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: uniq is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1
(use distinct instead) (called from __pry__ at (pry):8)
```

Quando tento seguir a sugestão de usar o distinct sem parametros:

```
Answers.pluck('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at)').distinct()
   (0.4ms)  SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) FROM `answers`
NoMethodError: undefined method `distinct' for [3, 3]:Array
from (pry):33:in `__pry__'
```

com parâmetro:

```
Answers.pluck('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at)').distinct('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at)')
   (0.4ms)  SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) FROM `answers`
NoMethodError: undefined method `distinct' for [3, 3]:Array
from (pry):33:in `__pry__'

Answers.pluck('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at)').distinct(:created_at)
   (0.7ms)  SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) FROM `answers`
NoMethodError: undefined method `distinct' for [3, 3]:Array
from (pry):35:in `__pry__'
```

A maneira de se usar é outra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que quando você usa o pluck ele converte para um array e não passa o objeto adiante. O uniq que ele ta usando é um método da classe Array e não do ActiveRecord.

O certo seria assim:

```
Answer.distinct("mes").select("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) mes")
```

Acontece que o resultado não fica tão "legal". Então podemos fazer uma pequena conversão:

```
Answer.distinct("mes").select("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) mes").map{|m| m.mes}

Answer Load (3.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) mes FROM "answers"
=> [3.0]
```

Se não quiser que o resultado saia um array de floats é só colocar **.to_i** no final do m.mes